# how can i bypass this form? Is there a way to login into any id if i don't know the password?

Tags: javascript, html, sql

i have a form which i want to bypass. Is there a way to bypass this using javascript or any other technique? Also how can i make out that this form is sql vulnerable?

```html
<form method="post" action="/auth/login/">
<input type="hidden" name="next" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="Tpy2uWI03EnzWIN3COSUvuVh5GrcUICo">
<fieldset class="fieldset_main">
<table>
<tbody><tr>
<th class="requiredfield">
<label for="id_username">Username:</label></th>
<td colspan="2"><input id="id_username" maxlength="254" name="username" type="text">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th class="requiredfield">
<label for="id_password">Password:</label></th>
<td colspan="2"><input id="id_password" name="password" type="password">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>
<label for="id_rememberme">Keep me logged in:</label></th>
<td colspan="2"><input id="id_rememberme" name="rememberme" type="checkbox">
</td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
</fieldset>
<input type="submit" value="login" class="button">
</form>
```

Comment: You can't, and it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

OK. Here is the serious answer. it's not the FORM that needs to be secure, it's the back-end code that handles the data. If you enter non-sanitized content into queries, or don't properly handle/process/use the entered data, that's where the vector will be. The form is purely aesthetic